# Maxon EPOS and ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I am wondering if anybody has experience with Maxon EPOS controllers and ROS ?

There is a nice package from WPI, but it works with kernel 2.6 ...

The older versions of Ubuntu are not supported, and the new ROS versions are not running on the older Ubuntu systems ...

And the most annoying is that MAXON do no have forums or reliable support !
Thinking of tossing the EPOS controllers to the bin ...

Unless somebody can help.

Tnx ! Yaro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73777/maxon-epos-and-ros/) by [Yaroslav Tenzer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2468/yaroslav-tenzer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess, you nee to visit that

http://answers.ros.org/question/232717/maxon-motor-with-ros/

---

Originally posted by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) with karma: 167 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0